# Already in use:connect exception in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, jersey

I'm writing a client for Neo4j. I have resources and users node with create and createdfor relationships. In each view resources, I query the database 11 times. 
Running with 1 thread, everything goes fine. But when I run it with 40 threads the following exception arises: (I'm using java api for rest api of Neo4j and my client and server are on the same machine)

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.UserAgent$1.handle(UserAgent.java:68)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:553)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestRequest.post(ExecutingRestRequest.java:151)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:547)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:568)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:235)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
    at Neo4j.Neo4jRestClient.listFriends(Neo4jRestClient.java:530)
    at Neo4j.Neo4jRestClient.listFriends(Neo4jRestClient.java:590)
    at Neo4j.Neo4jRestClient.listFriends(Neo4jRestClient.java:590)
    at Neo4j.Neo4jRestClient.listFriends(Neo4jRestClient.java:590)
    at edu.usc.bg.base.DBWrapper.listFriends(DBWrapper.java:113)
    at edu.usc.bg.workloads.CoreWorkload.doActionGetFriends(CoreWorkload.java:2360)
    at edu.usc.bg.workloads.CoreWorkload.doTransaction(CoreWorkload.java:1065)
    at edu.usc.bg.base.ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:201)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Good question, I think jersey client is by default configured to use a limited pool of ports. Are you running on windows, there are some threads about this error condition, which point out that there are limited resources.

Comment: Actually by restarting the machine I'm using as client, this exception went away! It was interesting! And yes, I'm using windows. Thanks :)